# How many different developers have made contributions to Monero source code?

Tags: development

How many different developers have made commits to Monero source code?

How does this level of developer contribution compare to other cryptocurrencies of a similar marketcap?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looking at solely GitHub commits, there have been 46 contributors to the [bitmonero](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/graphs/contributors) repository. If we count contributors to other Monero related repositories such as [Kovri](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri) the number would be significantly larger.

There are many ways to track developer interest but [marketcap](https://www.coingecko.com/en?sort_by=market_cap) alone is not the best indicator. One of the most popular [developer score rankings](https://www.coingecko.com/en?sort_by=developer_score) is from CoinGecko which currently places Monero 5th among all cryptocurrencies. Just like Github, CoinGecko reports Monero as having [46 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/monero).

Bitcoin leads all cryptocurrencies with [347 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bitcoin). Ethereum comes in 2nd with [44 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum), Counterparty 3rd with [27 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/counterparty) and Siacoin 4th with [12 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/counterparty).

From that same Coingecko list, Dash in 6th place has [29 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/dash), Storjcoin in 7th place has [15 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/storjcoinx), the (now defunct) DAO in 8th place has [16 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/dao) and Ripple in 9th place has [19 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ripple) and Namecoin in 10th place has [25 contributors](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/namecoin)

The great majority of all cryptocurrencies are forked from Bitcoin and therefore will have a vastly inflated number of commits, and contributers, solely because of their merging of Bitcoin pull requests. This partially explains the reason why Monero only ranks 5th on the list above despite having more contributors than every project besides Bitcoin according to CoinGecko.

Monero is based on CryptoNote and has an entirely different codebase than Bitcoin. Developer interest is relatively high despite the much steeper learning curve (from those used to the Bitcoin codebase). The fact that [academic research](https://lab.getmonero.org/) of Monero is also higher than most other currencies might be a leading indicator of increased developer interest in the future as [documentation](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/blob/master/Doxyfile) to help with the learning curve improves.

Answer (score 7):

One of my favourite tools for tracking this is OpenHub, because I added in all the Monero sources (including the repositories for Kovri, the site, the forum, the core GUI, the research lab, and so on). You can find Monero on OpenHub here: https://www.openhub.net/p/monero

According to OpenHub's tracking, Monero is built on the effort of 127 contributors, from the end of 2013 to today. In the last 30 days alone we've had 352 commits, and welcomed 9 new contributors!

Answer (score 3):

According to [Coingecko](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/monero): **53** developers have contributed code to the bitmonero repository.

> - Stars:  **222**
> - Watchers:  **76**
> - Forks:   **164**
> - Total Issues:  **277**
> - Closed Issues:   **187**
> - Merged Pull Requests:  **668**
> - Contributors:  **53**
> - Total new commits in the last 4 weeks:   **266**

However, this question is aiming a fast moving target. Keep refreshing the stats whenever you need it.